# const extern C-array linker multiple definitions

Tags: c++

I've got several source files for updating them. They refuse to compile for quite obvious reason (all uninteresting source stripped):

```
// hashset.h
class HashSet {
    unsigned prime = 0; // Index to table size (c++11 syntax)
    unsigned long table_size () const { return prime_list [prime]; }
};

//hashet.cpp
const unsigned long prime_list [] = {53, 97, 193, 389, 769,
      1543, 3079, 6151, 12289, 24593, 49157, 98317};
```

`prime_list` is undefined when called from `HashSet::table_size` in the header. I tried to fix the source, adding `extern const unsigned long prime_list [];` to the header and `extern` to this array definition. After `make clean && make` I got

```
g++ main.o dictionary.o hashset.o  -o spell
dictionary.o:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `num_primes'
main.o:(.rodata+0x4): first defined here
dictionary.o:(.rodata+0x20): multiple definition of `prime_list'
main.o:(.rodata+0x20): first defined here
hashset.o:(.rodata+0x4): multiple definition of `num_primes'
main.o:(.rodata+0x4): first defined here
hashset.o:(.rodata+0x20): multiple definition of `prime_list'
main.o:(.rodata+0x20): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As I found out, in fact if just `prime_table` is defined as

```
// hashset.cpp
extern const unsigned long prime_list [] = {53, 97, 193, 389, 769,
      1543, 3079, 6151, 12289, 24593, 49157, 98317};
```

and the body of `table_size ()` is moved to `hashset.cpp` (to avoid compilation errors), I get these linker errors. Without `extern` I have no errors. Why is it so? I have only one definition of this array, I do not expose it in any manner to other my source files (I do not put `extern const unsigned long prime_list [];` to the header now). How it can be multiply defined?

To be clear, my source now:

```
// hashset.h
class HashSet {
    unsigned prime = 0; // Index to table size (c++11 syntax)
    unsigned long table_size () const;
};

//hashet.cpp
extern const unsigned long prime_list [] = {53, 97, 193, 389, 769,
      1543, 3079, 6151, 12289, 24593, 49157, 98317};
unsigned long HashSet::table_size () const {
     return prime_list [prime];
}
```

Now `extern` in the `.cpp` is unnecessary, but I just wonder, what's wrong? And is there a way to put back the body of `table_size()` to the header file to allow it to be inline?

**upd** `prime_list` and `prime_table` are the same object. I mistakenly changed the name while shortening the source for this post; fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove extern. It should be fine.

For putting the method to header file , just declare the array with extern in header file.

```
 extern const unsigned long prime_table [];
```

Also you are not getting errors because of prime_table , but num_primes.

Works perfectly for me .

Build of configuration Debug for project tmpCheck **

make all 
Building file: ../src/hashset.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/hashset.d" -MT"src/hashset.d" -o "src/hashset.o" "../src/hashset.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/hashset.cpp

Building file: ../src/tmpCheck.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/tmpCheck.d" -MT"src/tmpCheck.d" -o "src/tmpCheck.o" "../src/tmpCheck.cpp"
Finished building: ../src/tmpCheck.cpp

Building target: tmpCheck
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++  -o "tmpCheck"  ./src/hashset.o ./src/tmpCheck.o
Finished building target: tmpCheck

Build Finished **

```
 #ifndef HASHSET_H_
 #define HASHSET_H_

  extern const unsigned long prime_list [];
  // hashset.h
  class HashSet {
     unsigned prime ; // Index to table size (c++11 syntax)
   public:
      HashSet():prime(0){
        //
      }
      unsigned long table_size () const { return prime_list [prime]; }

  };
  #endif /* HASHSET_H_ */

   #include "hashset.h"
   //hashet.cpp
   const unsigned long prime_list [] = {53, 97, 193, 389, 769,
      1543, 3079, 6151, 12289, 24593, 49157, 98317};
```

Comment: If I remove `extern` from `.cpp` and add `extern` declaration to the header, I get the same error about multiple definition.

And about prime_table: that's my fault, I renamed it from prime_list while typing the post. Actually, I get errors related to both these variables.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if usage of extern specificator, suggested by @Adnan Akbar haven`t solved you issue, then it **might be caused by multiply inclusion of header files**.
So in that case there is a simple solution to you problem:
**use conditional translation directives** or
#pragma once in your "hashset.h"